# How to get data inside a Throwable Scala object?

Tags: java, scala, play-json

How I get information inside a `Throwable` Scala object?

The code is an example about `throwable.getMessage`.

```scala
JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List('eoh' is undefined on object: {"store":"8767565","sku":"1983278364782364782"}),WrappedArray())))))
```

I need to extract `JsResultException`, `JsonValidationError` as string, message `'eoh' is undefined on object` message and JSON before `object:`.

Is this for make graceful log.

Answer (score 2):

Consider converting `JsResultException.errors` which is

```
Seq[(JsPath, Seq[JsonValidationError])]
```

where `JsonValidationError.errors` is yet another sequence `Seq[String]`, into a simpler tuple

```
Seq[(JsPath, String)]
```

like so

```
case JsResultException(errors) =>
  errors.map { case (path, validationErrors) => path -> validationErrors.map(_.messages.mkString(",")).mkString(",") }
```

This would produce a more managable structure similar to

```
List((/id,error.path.missing), (/name,error.path.missing))
```

instead of

```
List((/id,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))), (/name,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))]
```

Here is a working example

```
case class User(name: String, id: Int)
object User {
  implicit val formats = Json.format[User]
}

val raw = """{ "nam": "mario", "i": 5 }"""

try {
  Json.parse(raw).as[User]
} catch {
  case JsResultException(errors) =>
    errors.map { case (path, validationErrors) => path -> validationErrors.map(_.messages.mkString(",")).mkString(",") }
}
```

Also consider [using validation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJson#Using-validation) to avoid throwing exceptions like so

```
Json.parse(raw).validate[User] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[User] => s
  case JsError(errors) => 
    errors.map { case (path, validationErrors) => path -> validationErrors.map(_.messages.mkString(",")).mkString(",") }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the scala.util.Try and pattern match the Failure.

```
import scala.util._

def someExceptionThrowingMethod(): T = ???

Try(someExceptionThrowingMethod()) match {
    case Success(t: T) => ???
    case Failure(exception: Throwable) => exception match {
        case JsResultException((_, JsonValidationError(headMessage :: _) :: _, _) :: _) => 
          //here headMessage is the 'eoh' is undefined on object: {"store":"8767565","sku":"1983278364782364782"} message you wrote above
        case otherException: Throwable => ???
    }
}
```

Comment: For this case there's no real reason to do that instead of pattern-matching the exception in `try-catch`.